# Can i pass another model object to be used in Html.BeginForm?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two models which is connected. To simplify lets say I have a Post and Comment. When the details page Post, i want to build a form for posting a comment.

I can do that easily with just plain **html**. But I wish to use the `Html.BeginForm`.

First I pass a new Comment object to the details page from the controller.

```
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Details";
  Comment newComment = ViewBag.Comment;
 }

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Comments", FormMethod.Post))
{
   @Html.EditorFor(newCooment => newComment.Comment, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } 
})
```

But how can i tell the `HtmlHelper` to use my Comment model? ("`newComment =>` ... " does not work)

Comment: thats the problem with MVC, you bind only one model to one page and it complicates everything

Comment: You need to use ViewModels now.

Comment: Either add Comment to your view model or put the form/editor in a partial view. (I personally wouldn't label Separation of Concerns as complicating everything)

Comment: @Charlie that is just simply not true at all.

Comment: @No1_Melman then please expose the process to bind few models in one html page in MVC I am interested

Comment: @No1_Melman this is still only one model composed of 2 objects, if you need to bring a model and get the other one as a post you just overload the tunnel because of MVC limitations

Comment: @Charlie Models are objects... they are interchangeable. I have a ViewModel with 2 Models on it. These ViewModels and Models are described by C# POCO Classes. I.e. they are all classes so they are all the same object wise

Comment: I agree with you I just don't get why I am wrong when i say in MVC you bind ONE model of everything you may need or not and so you overload the tunnel, there is many other technologies replacing MVC because of the over using of server power and size of useless datas in each request, where you call only datas needed and not a model of 50 submodels because you can only bind one model in the razor view...

Comment: @Charlie well take Angular for example, or Knockout, they both bind 1 object to the page... Each object has "sub" objects - properties and methods. Its common practice to bind one model, I don't see why this is a limitation - there are no limitations

Comment: @No1_Melman yes this is all calculated client side, you have one model that you build with what you call from server and what user gives you and eventually post some data to the server, this way you only ask what you need to the server and send what you want to it, so you are right you have one model but this huge model is built client side and the server side models can stay specific to what they relate, this is more clear in code and less heavy in tunnel, though I agree with your answer which is the only way to achieve this in MVC but 'comment' model is brought while its not needed on get

Comment: @Charlie I sort of see what you're saying, but I can't imagine this to be a problem. You don't have to set any properties on the ViewModel, they can be returned null to MVC. So in this sense they aren't getting rebuilt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this happens in your controller. You need to have a view model which is a container for all the objects you want to pass to your view. In your view you then take advantage of the `@Model` property to access this VM.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index
    {
        var myViewModel = new MyViewModel 
             {
                 Post = post,
                 Comment = comment // assumed that these have been read from a DB
             };

        return View(myViewModel);
    }
}
```

The view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
     public Post Post {get;set;}
     public Comment Comment {get;set;}
}
```

In your View:

```
@model some.namespace.to.viewmodel.MyViewModel

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{

}

@Model <-- this is your MyViewModel instance you created in the controller
@Model.Comment <-- this has your Comment in
@Model.Post <-- this has your Post in
```

In the controller we do this `return View(myViewModel)`. This is telling the Razor engine that we want to set the `@Model` to our `ViewModel` and use it in our page.

I tend to stay clear of helper functions that create a whole bunch of html. I like full control over my HTML so I use the `@Html.TextBoxFor()` or the `@Html.TextAreaFor()` those "low level" helpers. If I want absolute control then I just write the HTML my self! The `id` properties should relate to your object levels:

`<input id="Post.Name" type="text" />`

It's kind of the architecture of MVC right, so you have Models which define the DB Domain. You have Views which show the model information. You have controllers which **should** delegate getting the models from the DB and sending them to the page. To get multiple Models to the page we need to use a ViewModel.

The semantics are important and widely used through many systems. Web and Desktop, so they are pretty important to understand.

In my products, I use the N-Tier architecture approach. I have services, DALs, Controllers, ViewModels, Models, DTOs.

DTOs are what I map models to, it stands for Domain Transfer Objects. So I got my Domain Model, I may not want everything on it (I don't use navigation properties for example so my DTOs have those navigation properties), in order to reduce it I create a DTO which is what is used around my system to transport that data. When I want to save that data I map it back to the Domain Model and persist to the database.

A key example is if you are using the ASP.NET Identity stuff. So ASP.NET went down the route of making the authentication EF Code First friendly. If you look at the User model for this, it has a tonne of properties and navigation's that I don't need to use. Especially if you just want to register a user.

My registration DTO will have a field my User does not. `ConfirmPassword`, I want it on my register so that I can confirm that the original password is what they meant it to be. But it stops at my validation layer, past then, it gets completely dropped - when we've confirmed the passwords match I only need the original password they entered.

Comment: I get it. Just seems a annoying i have to wrap it up in a new model. I guess the reason i want to do it this way and not just do a Html is that i will get the validation already on the comment model?

Comment: I'm sure there are validation helpers for individual controls. see update to post for address of the "annoying wrap up in new model"